# Как сделать проверку?

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, логику или шаги как это сделать правильно.

Есть в базе метка(is_allowed). Когда любой пользователь(не  авторизированный/авторизированный) заходит на сайт и данная метка false, то вместо страницы входа(или любой другой страницы) показывалась страница, например "Запрещено".

Каким образом это делать? Нужно в каждом контроллере прописывать Access => rules ? Или это можно сделать в одном месте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток.

Варинтов сделать довольно много. Несколько примеров:

- можно, как Вы написали, добавить AccessRules, по которому редиректит на страницу с информацией.
- можно проверять вручную в beforeAction базового контроллера и либо редиректить, либо рендерить нужную вьюху.
- Можно реализовать через правила роутов, если они используются.

На мой взгляд, нужно исходить из самого проекта. Если там активно используются AccessRules, то добавить еще одно правило проще. А может быть наоборот, для каждого контролера заданы свои правила и трудно будет уследить, чтобы новое правило нигде не оказалось переопределенным. В этом случае проще 2-ой вариант.

Answer (score 0):

Добрый день.

Вам уже отвечали на другом форуме, что AccessControl на работает с метками. Работает с правилами доступа. 
У него есть два правила доступа - "@" и "?", что означает, авторизованные пользователи и гости соответственно.
Это простейший способ контроля.

Можно использовать RBAC, где более гибкая настройка правил доступа.

В любом случае, чтобы использовать Вашу метку в базе - надо rbac, который будет проверять значение этой метки. И, в зависимости от её значения, предоставлять или нет доступ к действию или контроллеру.
В AccessControl уже всё сделано за Вас, достаточно указать к каким действиям имеет доступ гость, а к каким авторизованный пользователь.
Делается это всё через поведение. Прописываете в каждом контроллере или создаёте свой основной контроллер, от которого будете наследовать остальные.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'only' => ['login', 'logout', 'signup'],
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['login', 'signup'],
                    'roles' => ['?'],
                ],
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'actions' => ['logout'],
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

В данном примере доступ к действиям login, logout, signup доступен гостям, остальные действия, в том числе и logout, доступны авторизованным пользователям.
Подробней [здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/security-authorization.md)

p.s. объяснил как мог)))